# Test Class not working with proper logic

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage

```
trigger DeleteRelatedTasks on Case (after update) {
    list<case> relatedCase = new list<case>();
    // Get the approved case record
    for (case myCase : Trigger.new) {
        if ( (myCase.VXRecordTypeName__c == 'Credit') &&
             (myCase.VXTL_Approval_Status__c == 'Approved' ||
              myCase.VXTL_Approval_Status__c == 'Decline')) {

            relatedCase.add(myCase);
        }
    }
    if(!relatedCase.isEmpty()) {
    delete [SELECT Id FROM Task 
          WHERE WhatId = :relatedCase AND 
                Subject LIKE '%CREDIT CLAIM%'];
    }

}
```

and test Class is

```
@isTest
private class DeleteRelatedTasksTest {

    static testMethod void updateCase() {
     case c = new case();
     c.RecordType        = [select Id from RecordType where Name = 'Credit' and SobjectType = 'Case'];
     c.Type              = 'Request for Credit';
     c.Origin            = 'Phone';
     c.Status            = 'Open';
     c.Priority          = 'Medium';
     c.Subject           = 'Test Vish';
     c.AccountId         = '0010x000007gIDa';
     c.ContactId         = '0030x000001jSaN';
     //c.Owner             = '005G00000085qrF';

     insert c;

     Task newTask = new task();
     newTask.subject       = 'Approve Credit Claim';
     newTask.Priority      = 'High';
     newtask.Status        = 'Open';
     newTask.whatId        = c.id;

     insert newTask; 

     c.VXCSR_Approval_Status__c = 'Approved';
     c.VXCSR_Remarks__c         = 'Approved';
     c.VXTL_Approval_Status__c  = 'Approved';

     update c;          

    }
}
```

Not sure what modifications are required.

Comment: What is your issue? Isn't it needed the field `VXRecordTypeName__c' be populated in your test class?

Comment: VXRecordTypeName__c is a formula field referring to RecordType's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create test records for all of the stuff you're doing here:

```
Account a = new Account(Name='Test Account');
insert a;
...
c.AccountId = a.Id;
```

Also, you should be using RecordTypeId:

```
c.RecordTypeId = Schema.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Credit').getRecordTypeId();
```